# Sending JS PNG URl through POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a difficult time with something that is a rather simple thing...I know my brain is fried for the day.

I am using a JS signature script to record a signature to a PNGURL. I am trying to POST the data to another page so I can process it via PHP.

```
function signatureSave() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.1);
    document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;



};
```

I didn't realize that the data is far to long to use GET, but I am unfamiliar with how to POST it. I have looked through other posts about posting, but cannot find a working example.

Edit of attempted code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.1);
document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;
alert(dataURL);
$.post("signatureaccepted.php", { signature: dataURL });'
```

Comment: post how/where? via an ajax call? or a normal form submission?

Comment: Normal form is all that is needed - I do not need to return that page. The page name is signatureaccepted.php. I'm hoping the user calls that function, the posts, and redirects them to the posted to page.

Comment: then you stuff the data url into a form field and submit it like any other formfield. a data url is plaintext, after all.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to do that properly is the thing.

Comment: sure you do. you're already doing almost the exact thing with your code above. `document.getElementById('#form_field_you_want_to_use').value = dataUrl`, then submit the form that field is in.

Comment: I see what your saying - I updated my code..I can't seem to get it to go right though. It isn't redirecting to the next page. Am I missing something?